# What technologies exist to integrate 3D content with web-site?

Tags: html, css, 3d

I am web-developer. I would like to integrate 3D Content into my web-site. The level of integration should allow something like 3D Cube floating above HTML Content. Moreover, I want 3D Content to be interactive, i.e. one should be able to click on certain side of the cube and get some JavaScript code executed in same way as if somebody clicked a button.

I have seen some demos with [CSS3 3D Transforms in HTML 5](http://www.zachstronaut.com/lab/isocube.html). It's even possible to render HTML Content on 3D Objects like images and buttons, but they don't seem to allow something as sophisticated as floating cube.

Is it possible today? Which technologies should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best options you have available today are [CSS transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj665791(v=vs.85).aspx), and/or the [Canvas element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). With CSS you can perform various transformations, even including the construction of an [animated cube](http://jsfiddle.net/u48KL/) ([easier](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html) with `preserve-3d`).

Comment: Does Flash offer any kind of 3D Rendering? Will I be able to click through transparent background?

Answer (score 2):

After some research online found [XML3D](http://www.xml3d.com/) and [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org/) projects. They offer integration with DOM and JavaScript, XML-like scene description and even programmable shaders. Seems that it's exactly what I was looking for, however both projects are still in development :(.

Comment: An update: Firefox 4 (and I think Chrome) now support WebGL, so that X3DOM is supported out of the box on newer systems. On older systems, the necessary WebGL support may be disabled by default in Firefox. If you have a recent enough graphics card and update the drivers, you can enable it.  Still not prime time, for sure, but at least a large step forward.